# Accessing shared folder using proxy

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, network-shares

1. I have a client PC having a network of 192.168.19.x/24
2. I have a Server having a network of 193.168.19.x/24
3. I have a middle PC having both networks 193.168.19.x/24 and 192.168.19.x/24
4. My Server has a shared folder called test which the client needs to be accessed. So if my server is accessing this folder C:\test, my client must be able to access the shared folder using \\test
5. However, the server and client is in a different network due to infrastructure restrictions and i cannot use routing.

Is there a way/software for the client to access this folder on the server directly using the middle computer as a proxy?

**I do not want a 2 way access to this shared folder which is very troublesome.(Even though i know you can copy to the middle machine then copy to server is a solution)**

Comment: What you want is called routing. You want a router. The restrictions can then be enforced by a firewall.

Comment: Due to certain restrictions, i cannot use routing as well.

Comment: You can't share files if the two devices can't communicate. How about you tell us what you are allowed to do and we'll point you in the correct direction?